# Sharing an object between instances of a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, pragma

Good morning all,

Forgive me if the title is not too clear, I'll try to explain more here:

I am currently working with the ASI for VBS2. VBS2 executes functions from a VBS2 DLL plugin. I have my own application which I want to use to modify variables within that plugin whilst it is being used, to change what is being executed by VBS2. I began by, foolish as it may be, directly changing the variables with my application whilst the VBS2 program was running.

When this did not work I tested and found that the VBS2 program was using a different instance of the "message" object, in which I was storing the variable, to the one being accessed by my application.

What I would like to do is have my application access the same instance of the object being accessed by VBS2. I have experimented a bit with

```
#pragma data_seg(".testseg")
Message msg;
void foo(...); //etc.
#pragma data_seg()
```

but for some reason or another it still appears there are two instances being used.

I would greatly appreciate any and all help, and would add that C++ is a new language to me so please be gentle. :)

Thanks,
M

Comment: Do you expect the _function_ `foo()` to end in the _data_ segment `.testseg`? That may cause some conflicts with DEP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use linker flags to tell the linker to place that segment in sharable memory.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933104.aspx

I belive you need to add something like

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.testseg,RWS")
```

to your program. 
I'm not sure, this may only work in a DLL...

Comment: Oh, and you may need to declare your variables volatile to ensure the compiler actually reads them and doesn't cache the values in registers etc.

Comment: It would work anywhere, EXE's too. However, in this case, the only module that's shared between the "VBS2" process and the other process is the plugin DLL that both load.

Comment: Thank you very much John; having had a quick look am I right in beleiving that I can put that in front of the code I already have (i.e. #pragma data_seg(...))?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can't do this with standard C/C++ tools. Your program and the other program live in separate memory spaces and they are completely insulated from each other. If your program has administrative privileges, you can attempt to read & write the memory space of the other process using WriteProcessMemory():

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

But then there's a problem of finding the right object in that memory space.

It's not clear whether you have the source for the plugin. If you do, there are other interprocess communication techniques that can be utilised. None as simple as just changing the variable, unfortunately.

Comment: I do have the source, yes. I was just having a think, would this work if I had my application modifying a variable in another DLL, and having the VBS2 DLL access that variable instead? Or would this create the same problem as before? I may be going about this completely the wrong way; the VBS2 ASI plugin sends messages to VBS2 to execute various scripts within the engine. All I want to do is dynamically change which messages are being sent, which I know can be done. Thank you very much for your response, too.